# meaning of conditional statement

Tags: php, boolean-logic

In a piece of code I found the following conditional statement:

```
if ( !defined('MY_CONSTANT') || MY_CONSTANT !== false )
```

and I am wondering what this may achieve that is not achieved by simply stating:

```
if ( MY_CONSTANT !== false )
```

..
is it not so, that in case MY_CONSTANT !== false then it MUST also be defined, making the first argument of the first example superfluous, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `or` conditional stops evaluating as soon as one of the conditions is true.

Since the conditions are evaluated left to right, and trying to check an undefined constant yelds an exception, you first check if it is defined, and then for its value.

If the constant is not defined, the `if` statement exits, and doesn't try to check the value.

Comment: all the answers are correct, and say more or less the same thing, I chose this one as it explain how it actually works. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If the constant may be undefined at that point, trying to access it will produce a warning on properly configured servers. You don't want those filling up your error logs, hence the `defined()` check.

Answer (score 1):

Your version and the first version are not the same:

If it is not defined, the first condition of the first version will be true, and it will 'trigger'.

If it is not defined, your version will be false. (well, at least raise an error ;) )

Answer (score 0):

no, because if `MY_CONSTANT` is not defined, PHP will give you an error message :

```
Notice:  Use of undefined constant MY_CONSTANT
```

Answer (score 0):

If `MY_CONSTANT` is not defined, PHP will do two things:

- Log and/or display an error when you try to use it
- Interpret `MY_CONSTANT` as if it were the literal string `"MY_CONSTANT"`